# Two way QTcpSocket File Transfer issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtcpsocket, qtnetwork

I'm a bit stumped with this and don't have a whole lot of experience with file transfer so hopefully I'm just doing something daft.

Anyway. The problem. I'm sending a file in chunks from my client to my server. This works fine. During sending my client is waiting for progress messages periodically so I know how much data has been sent. However when I send any progress messages the file transfer times out on the server side.

I'm fairly sure this isn't a problem with the client side code so I'll leave that out. I've commented the two lines that seem to kill things in the sendFeedback() method. With the two commented out lines, waitforReadyRead() will time out in the main loop almost immediately. It's almost like writing out to the socket blocks any information that was on the socket from being read and stops any further data from being read.

It feels like I'm missing something with sockets when sending and receiving "at the same time" but I can't find anything in documentation.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

File Receiving Code:

```
const int Timeout = 30 * 1000;
QTcpSocket tcpSocket;

if (!tcpSocket.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
    emit error(tcpSocket.error());
    return;
}

while(totalBytesRead<blockSize && !error && !success)
{       

    int toRead = blah blah blah
    //loop until chosen chunk amount is available on socket
    while (tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() < toRead) 
    {
        //if no reply from socket, exit
        if (!tcpSocket.waitForReadyRead(Timeout))
        {
            error=true;
            break;
        }
    }
        //read data
    int actuallyRead = in.readRawData(datas, toRead);
    //if data read
    if(actuallyRead)
    {                   
        sendFeedback(&tcpSocket, actuallyRead);
        //write the chunk to disk
        out.writeRawData(datas,actuallyRead);
        if(totalBytesRead == blockSize)
        {
                success = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my feedback function:

```
void FileServerThread::sendFeedback(QTcpSocket* tcpSocket, int bytesActuallyRead)
{
    //send some progress back to the client
    QByteArray bytesReadArray;
    QDataStream out(&bytesReadArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);                    
    out << bytesActuallyRead;

    //feedback requires this but fails with these 2 lines
    //tcpSocket->write(bytesReadArray);
    //tcpSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
}
```

Comment: Rather than checking if bytes are available first, I think you should be sitting on waitForReadyRead. Then when that returns true, read whatever is available and keep track of the amount of bytes read. You need to be pulling data off the socket as it arrives, rather than waiting for it to buffer up to an amount that you want to deal with.